# Computational advantages of various notations for electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, soft-question, differential-geometry, education, notation

Most undergraduate electromagnetism classes and textbooks use vector notation to describe Maxwell's equations.  However, there are other notations like differential geometry and geometric calculus that simplify the equations and derivations using them.  (See, for example, [E&M and geometry - a historical perspective](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122946/) or the paper [Teaching electromagnetic field theory using differential forms](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=554670&tag=1) by Warnick et al.)

My question is this: does using differential forms or geometric calculus give any *computational* (particularly, paper-and-pencil) advantage in non-relativistic electromagnetism?

In other words, if I'm trying to find the electromagnetic fields and/or potentials of a particular system, will these other notations yield **shorter calculations**?  Can you please give a specific (nontrivial) example?

Comment: Hi Ted, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Traditionally we haven't hosted many education questions, so people may consider this off topic; if so, we can send it to [matheducators.SE]. I would draw people's attention to [this meta question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4244) on the topicality of these questions.

Comment: I'm willing to jettison the education language.  That's more for context than content.

Comment: This isn't enough for an answer, but in my experience, doing usual vector calculus with difforms is easier. No need to remember how to calculate area and volume elements, including calculating the norm of a cross product for the area element, all these things "calculate themselves". Also calculation of exterior derivatives in curvilinear coordinates (but to a lesser extent, in cartesian too) is much easier than it is with div/curl, although as far as I recall, calculating hodge duals in noncartesian coordinates can be a pain.

Comment: @Uldreth My experience is similar to yours.  Derivatives and differential elements are easy, but the Hodge operator (and pullback operator) can be messy.  Maybe there's a "conservation of effort" rule here, but I'm asking because I'm a novice with these techniques.

Comment: I'd also add, that though I haven't done any calculations with it, the use of moving frames (for orthogonal coordinates) the same way we usually do in vector calculus might be beneficial. It makes hodge duals trivial, but exterior derivatives more complicated. However if you calculate all structure-coefficients at the start of the calculation, say, then I'd say calculating exterior derivatives might be more of a routine than with vector calculus notation. (Compared to a coordinate frame, I mean)

Comment: I was an undergraduate a long time ago (1962-1966).  Back then tensor analysis/differential geometry were mostly graduate level courses.  Have curricula changed so much that physics undergraduates now possess those skills prior to taking E&M?

Comment: @LewisMiller I guess this varies with universities. In my case (University of Szeged), tensor analysis with indices is taught in undergradiate courses. When I was at that level we also had very elementary but modern differential geometry (the coordinate-independent one), however it was an experiment and it failed, so we are back to indices now. Basically students couldn't deal with it. That included me too, but it was actually the course, which set my direction in terms os studies as it fascinated me.

Comment: @Lewis There are a handful of people who argue that vector notation adds unnecessary conceptual hurdles to understanding E&M, and that these other representations are more compact and elegant. So, they're teaching differential calculus or geometric algebra from the beginning of the course.  That's all well and good, but I'm more of a pragmatist,  so I'm curious if, at the end of the day, I can calculate things more easily if I invest the time to learn these other techniques.

Comment: @TedCorcovilos  There are certain things that can be calculated more easily (and elegantly) with tensor techniques.  I've used them extensively in my research in nuclear physics (with the Dirac equation, see: https://journals.aps.org/prc/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevC.14.706 ).  I'm just concerned that undergraduates might not have mastered them sufficiently to benefit from their use.

Comment: I'm disappointed that my question was closed.  Those who voted to close it, can you suggest ways to improve it rather than just a blanket "no"?  I think I have a legitimate question, but perhaps I didn't state it in the best way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a paper for you to ponder on:

[Teaching electromagnetic field theory using differential forms](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=554670&tag=1)

Excerpt from the abstract:

> computational simplifications result from the use of forms:
>   derivatives are easier to employ in curvilinear coordinates,
>   integration becomes more straightforward, and families of vector
>   identities are replaced by algebraic rules.

Comment: Yep.  I have that paper on my desk.  However, after working some example problems with both differential forms and vector notation, my opinion is that the same amount of work was required.  This is exactly what prompted my question.

Comment: It might help to add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are definite advantages of differential forms, geometric calculus, and four vectors over 3d Gibbs vector algebra and vector calculus.

Specifically you can solve for the electromagnetic field first ... and then let someone break it into electric and magnetic parts later if they feel like it (if at all).

For instance the field due to a non accelerating point charge can get its direction expressed as an outer product of 1) the four velocity of the charge producing the field at the event of the intersection of the past light cone of the event having the field and the world line of the charge producing the field and 2) that null vector connecting the two events. In the instantaneously comoving inertial frame of the charge producing the field back then, it's all electric field. But you don't have to pick a frame and compute an electric field and a magentic field. You can just compute the Faraday field (electromagnetic field) directly.

Comment: I'm specifically excluding 4-vectors, etc. The question is about doing calculations in a nonrelativistic way.

Comment: @TedCorcovilos A goal of teaching a relativistic theory in a non relativistic way seems to aim to not actually teach the theory. But sure, you can still pick a frame and compute everything in that one frame and never change frames and then you don't have to worry about Galilean Relativity versus SR. But you should still just compute the electromagnetic field as if you cared about Relativity then just take the components in your one frame to get you the electric and magnetic fields in that one frame.

Comment: I see your point of view, and I'd consider it for a graduate course.  But teaching special relativity and EM concurrently to students who have never seen either seems like too much to swallow. Purcell's book makes an attempt, but even in his case SR is more a justification than an end result.